# Android: Overriding putExtra

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile, broadcastreceiver

I have a class that extends BroadcastReciever, so it is only called when the alarm is triggered.

I put as extra an int variable with a key of "distance".
However, the distance changes, so I try to override the putExtra (in another function) but it doesn't get the new value of the distance.
I did toasts to double check if it goes inside the function where it should override the distance value (and it does go inside the function).

My questions are,

1. Is it even possible to override the putExtra of the same key?
2. Is there a way to be able to change the value of the distance?

Here's how i implemented it:

This code runs when user clicks a button

```
    intentAlarm = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
    intentAlarm.putExtra("number", number);
    intentAlarm.putExtra("distance", getDistance());

     alarm_pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0,
                            intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Where I "override" the distance, where I could get the new distance

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        intentAlarm.putExtra("distance", getDistance());
    }
```

Comment: when calling `getBroadcast` use different `requestCode`s